# SQL math syntax difficulty with division

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can't understand why I can't get the correct answer. I'm trying to calculate a net margin percentage but the divide portion is being ignored. Hopefully really simple one?

```
SUM(
    (dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Sales2.TotalSales - dbo.K3_TradeTeam_SalesReturn3.TotalCredits)
    ISNULL(dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Purch1.TotalPurchases, 0) / 
           dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Sales2.TotalSales
   ) AS NetMargin
```

Comment: Please choose real titles. They should summarize your question.

Comment: Seems one or more operators missing (Commas, Brackets, Math Operators)

Comment: In addition to the missing operator, you could be seeing discrepencies due to implicit conversions. i.e. dividing an integer by an integer will result in an integer, even if one does not exactly divide the other, so you get unexpected results. e.g. `SELECT 100 / 80` will return `1`, however `SELECT 100.0 / 80` will return `1.25`.

Comment: You might want to post your schema, full query, some sample data and the expected output.  Certainly any error message would be helpful, too.

Comment: Given what you are calulating, I think it is unlikely, but if allthose values are integers, you are suffering from Integermath and need to cast at least one to a decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a net margin you probably want an expression like this,

```
(
    SUM(
            dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Sales2.TotalSales
        - 
            COALESCE(dbo.K3_TradeTeam_SalesReturn3.TotalCredits, 0.0)
        -
            COALESCE(dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Purch1.TotalPurchases, 0.0)
       )
/ 
    SUM(
            dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Sales2.TotalSales
       )
) AS NetMargin
```

However, without knowing your schema I couldn't say for sure. This would also fail miserable when you have `0.0` total sales.

---

I'm assuming that your want the sum of net profits for each realtion divided by the sum of the total revenue for each relation. This would give you the cumulative profit margin for all relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The sql logic should work. 
Are you sure that TotalPurchases is not null? Because this makes it look like the devide is ignored, but the devide just returns 0. So I'm doing minus zero!

examples:

```
select SUM((200 - 100) - ISNULL(100, 0) / 10) AS NetMargin --returns 90
select SUM((200 - 100) - ISNULL(null, 0) / 10) AS NetMargin --return 100
```

Comment: Total Purchases is sometimes null since the view it pulls from uses a left outer join to bring in purchase costs where they exist but for the majority of rows this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

When I am having trouble getting a math formula to work, I change the select temporarily to simply see the values of each of the fields as well as the calculation. Then I can do the calualtion manually to see how I am getting the results I am getting which alwmost always points me to the problem.

```
select 
    dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Sales2.TotalSales, 
    dbo.K3_TradeTeam_SalesReturn3.TotalCredits,
    ISNULL(dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Purch1.TotalPurchases, 0), 
    dbo.K3_TradeTeam_Sales2.TotalSales 
From...
```

I also never do a division without a case statement to handle the divisor being 0 problem. Even if I think it can never happen, I have seen it burn people too often not to consider that something (including bad data entry) might make it happen in the future.